# Can't enable net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf

Tags: debian, networking, ipv6

I can't get `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf to = 1`.
Goes back to 0 after every reboot causing eth0 to never auto-acquire a global IPv6 address. I am running a headless Debian Jessie (kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64).

After correctly assigning an ULA address to my eth0 like this:

Content of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
address fd69:6666::
netmask 64
```

What i've tried so far:

- adding `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`;
- setting `net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=1` and `net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` *before* eth0 autoconf. They correctly stay 1 after rebooting;
- making sure it's not set anywhere else (`grep -iR 'autoconf' /etc`).
- appending `pre-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=1` to the `inet6 static` stanza of my /etc/network/interfaces;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
autoconf 1
```

to your `inet6 static` stanza.
See [`man interfaces`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en).

Comment: Well that was easy!